# Study the uniform convergence of $\int_0^{0.5}\frac{dx}{x|\ln x|^\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals

Using Cauchy criterion prove uniform convergence of parametric integral on given set.

$\int_0^{0.5}\frac{dx}{x|\ln x|^\alpha}, \alpha \in[1+\delta,+\infty), \delta>0$

My work.

$\exists E$ st $0<E<A<A_1<0.5$ need to prove that  $\sup_{\alpha\geq1+\delta}|\int_A^{A_1}\frac{dx}{x|\ln x|^\alpha}| < \epsilon$.Problem is from here I want to get rid of $\alpha$ in the denominator but I can't replace with $1+\delta$. How continue from there?

EDIT.

Seeing hint at comments I did some extra work. Let $x=e^{-y}$.$\int_A^{2A}\frac{dx}{x|lnx|^\alpha}=\int_{ln(1/A)}^{ln(1/2A)}\frac{dy}{|y|^\alpha}$ because $\alpha>1$ integral is convergent so remainder goes to $0$.

Comment: Convergence as what goes to what? What you seem to be trying to prove is that these functions are uniformly integrable (i.e. the integrals go to zero uniformly as you shrink the integration domain, no matter where you shrink it and no matter which function you were working with). This seems like a weird thing to do in this Riemann setting.

Comment: Hint. Let $x=e^{-y}.$

Comment: $y \in (-\ln(2A), -\ln A)$, not $y \in (\ln A, \ln(2A))$. And what happened to $\alpha$?

Comment: @metamorphy No, for $\alpha>1$ the logarithm is enough to make the singularity integrable.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Is now right?

Comment: $x$ goes from $0$ to $1/2$ and $y=-\ln x$  so $y$ goes from  $\infty$ to $\ln 2$  and we get $\int_{\ln 2}^{\infty}\frac {dy}{y^{\alpha}}.$